# Login with python using database

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

Im trying to make the user log in whereas if they type the correct username and password they will be able to do so but I keep getting an error when I enter the login details

```
def login(self):
    global con
    if self.txt_user.get() == "" or self.txt_pass.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")
    else:
        try :
            con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="employee")
            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from employeelist where username=%s",self.txt_user.get())
            row=cur.rowcount
            print(row)
            if row != None :
                cur.execute("select password from employeelist where username=%s", self.txt_pass.get())
                row1 = cur.rowcount
                print(row1)
                if(row1 != None):
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
                    m = menu
                    m.Menu(root) 
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Password. Please try again!")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error, Wrong Username or Password. Please try again!")
        except Exception as ex:
            con.close()
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `self.txt_user.get()` and `self.txt_pass.get()` are returning what you think they should be returning? Also, are you sure that `cur.rowcount` can return `None` rather than zero under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following issues:

- `rowcount` will be a number, never be `None`, so `if row != None` will be always `True`
- used `self.txt_pass.get()` in `SELECT ... WHERE username=%s` is incorrect, should use `self.txt_user.get()` instead

Under security consideration, normally we don't tell the user whether username or password is incorrect.  That will expose user information to hackers under brute force attack.  Just tell them either successful or failed is enough.  Also do not store plain text password in database.  Password should be encrypted.

Also you can use single SELECT to check the credentials:

```
    def login(self):
        user = self.txt_user.get().strip()
        passwd = self.txt_pass.get().strip() 
        if user == "" or passwd == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")
        else:
            try :
                con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="employee")
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT 1 from employeelist WHERE username = %s and password = %s", (user, passwd))
                if cur.rowcount == 1:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid credentials. Please try again!")
            except Exception as ex:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error due to: {str(ex)}", parent=self.root)
            finally:
                con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute(
    "select password from employeelist where username=%s",
    self.txt_pass.get()
)
```

You are using password (i.e. `self.txt_pass.get()`) to find username, so it wont find any records hence you're getting error all the time.ez fix

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the callproc option.
import pymysql

```
            try:
                conn = pymysql.Connect( 
                        host='localhost', 
                        user='root',  
                        passwd = '', 
                        db='testing' 
                        #,autocommit=True
                        )
                
                
                #pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
                cur = conn.cursor() 
                params = ('official',1)
                cur.callproc('getlogindetails',args=params)
                # cur.execute("call getlogindetails(?,?)", params)
                
                ls = list(cur.fetchall()) 

                #your logic here based on the list value

            finally:
                conn.close()
```

Procedure:
DELIMITER $$

```
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing`.`getlogindetails` $$
        CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getlogindetails`(in inusername 
                                                 varchar(100),in inloginid integer)
        BEGIN
            select  fname,id,lname from details where id < 10;
        END $$

        DELIMITER ;
```